# How to correctly compare a line in a text file to a user input using GUI

Tags: java, string, user-interface, bufferedreader, filewriter

I have been roaming around the internet collecting info and using them but I can't seem to successfully compare a line of text in a text file to a user input using gui

Filename : MainLogin.Java

```
String user, pass;

user = txtUser.getText();
pass = txtPass.getText();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("profiles.txt"))) {
    String sCurrentLine;

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);

        if (sCurrentLine.equals(user) && sCurrentLine.equals(pass)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful!");
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            dispose();
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Username and/or Password!");
        }
    }
}
catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is how I write in the text file using "registration" method

Filename : Registration.java

```
String name, user, pass, address;
int contactNo;
float deposit;

name = txtName.getText();
user = txtUser.getText();
pass = txtPass.getText();
address = txtPass.getText();
contactNo = Integer.parseInt(txtContact.getText());
deposit = Float.parseFloat(txtDeposit.getText());

//u = new User(name , user, pass, address, contactNo, deposit);

try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("profiles.txt", true));
    writer.write(name + "\r\n");
    writer.write(user + "\r\n");
    writer.write(pass + "\r\n");
    writer.write(address + "\r\n");
    writer.write(contactNo + "\r\n");
    writer.write(Float.toString(deposit) + "\r\n");
    //writer.write("------------------------------------------------------------");
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    // report
}
finally {
    try {
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {/*ignore*/}
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered!");

MainLogin ml = new MainLogin();
dispose();
```

Comment: `sCurrentLine.equals(user) && sCurrentLine.equals(pass)` So `sCurrentLine` should be equal to the username and to the password on the same time?

Comment: Beside your problem I think it's not a very nice and safe solution to write plain login credentials / user data into a file. You are using "\r" and "\n" when you write the things in your file, so it's not possible that the username and the password are in the same line.